# RegEx - One Group for each set of lines

Tags: java, regex

Say I have a text file that has content similar to the following:

```
021 Line one of section A.
021 Line two of Section A.
021 Line three of section A.
021 Part two of Line three of Section A.
021 We just skipped line four, but that's okay.
021 Back to line six.
Non-formatted lines to be ignored. This can be from 0 lines, to any number of lines, and the content can be any text.
033 Line 1 of Section B
033 Line 2 of Section B
033 Okay, that's enough.
```

Is it possible, in regex, to give me two groups, the first containing all the lines that start with `021`, and the second all the lines starting with `033`?

The line tokens would vary, but would always be `\d{3}`.

Comment: Why not make one regex with `\d{3]` and group in a `Map<String, List<String>>` wherein the key is the result of `\d{3}`. The regex would look like this: `(\d{3})(.*)` (assuming you do not enable newline matching with `*`). It's simpler than an `if else` solution with two regexes

Comment: Are the lines with the numbers always consecutive? Or can they be mixed?

Comment: @roookeee  -- The data I'm getting back in the lines will be heavily processed once loaded and split, and I need to keep CPU processing time as low as possible. So pre-splitting them up is  preferred. :)

Comment: @Thefourthbird - They would be mixed, so one group would be, say, 654, the very next would be 231, then 045, etc. (They're numbers, but are codes for return data, not an index of sorts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might capture the digits at the start in a capturing group and use a backreference `\1` to that group while repeating it.

This will give you the matches where the digits at the start are the same.

```
^(\d{3}) .*(?:\r?\n\1.*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yoA40p/4)

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect! Should brush up on my back-reference knowledge.